# how to update an IEnumerable class property

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have this code

```
private IEnumerable<HorasVM> InsertarCalendarioValores(IEnumerable<HorasVM> listaHoras, string proyectoId, DateTime fechaInicio, DateTime fechaFin)
  {
    IEnumerable<ValoresEnFecha> calendarioValoresFULCRUM;
    IEnumerable<ValoresEnFecha> calendarioValoresSERS;
    IEnumerable<ValoresEnFecha> calendarioValoresMATRIZ;
    decimal realizadoSERS;
    decimal realizadoMATRIZ;

    foreach (var item in listaHoras)
    {
      calendarioValoresFULCRUM = GetDesdeHasta(dbFULCRUM, proyectoId, item.EmpleadoId, fechaInicio, fechaFin, item.Type);
      calendarioValoresSERS = GetDesdeHasta(dbSERS, proyectoId, item.EmpleadoId, fechaInicio, fechaFin, item.Type);
      calendarioValoresMATRIZ = GetDesdeHasta(dbMATRIZ, proyectoId, item.EmpleadoId, fechaInicio, fechaFin, item.Type);

      foreach (var mes in calendarioValoresFULCRUM)
      {
        realizadoSERS = calendarioValoresSERS.Where(c => c.Fecha == mes.Fecha).FirstOrDefault().Realizado;
        realizadoMATRIZ= calendarioValoresMATRIZ.Where(c => c.Fecha == mes.Fecha).FirstOrDefault().Realizado;
        mes.Realizado += realizadoSERS + realizadoMATRIZ;
      }

      item.CalendarioValores = calendarioValoresFULCRUM;
    }

    return listaHoras;
  }
```

HorasVM is this class

```
public class HorasVM
{
    public int EmpleadoId { get; set; }
    public string ProyectoId { get; set; }
    public string EmpleadoNombre { get; set; }
    public decimal RealizadoAcumulado { get; set; }
    public decimal PlanificadoAcumulado { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public decimal PrevistoAcumulado => RealizadoAcumulado + PlanificadoAcumulado;

    public IEnumerable<ValoresEnFecha> CalendarioValores { get; set; }

}
```

And ValoresEnFecha is this class

```
public class ValoresEnFecha
{
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public decimal Realizado { get; set; }
    public decimal Planificado { get; set; }
}
```

In my method, I get this listaHoras

[image: listaHoras]

where the property CalendarioValores of each item is null and I want to calculate it so for each item in listaHoras I get the values and I assign them to each item

[image: item]

but when I update the item in listaHoras this item still has the CalendarioValores property unassigned.

```
item.CalendarioValores = calendarioValoresFULCRUM;
```

is not updating the property of each item of listaHoras

Any idea Please?

Regards

Comment: Have you tred to reproduce problem using a minimal code? A class with less properties, and a with less business logic? Reading the question is a bit hard. It's better to remove unnecessary properties, or methods which doesn't have anything to do with question.

Comment: Do you know that call for calendarioValoresFULCRUM = GetDesdeHasta(//etc returns anything?

Comment: I would make IEnumerable<HorasVM> listaHoras  as IList<HorasVM>. IEnumerable<T> is readonly

Comment: Thanks @level_zebra that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using read only IEnumerable type instead of List
Thanks